# How can I replace ^I into tab spaces in vim editor for .java file?

Tags: sed, vim, ed

When I open my .java file in vim, I could see a couple of lines prefixed with one / more `^I` characters. It looks like tabs in Eclipse that has got converted into `^I`.

I would like to replace a single `^I` into spaces with 4 characters.

E.g

`^I^I^I^IList<History> rulePackagesHistory = result.getHistory();`

How can do that in vim editor?

Comment: If you have `set list` or `set listchars` in your `.vimrc`, [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4304/20429) might be the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

After that, each new tab character entered will be changed to 4 spaces, old tabs don't. You must type:

```
:retab
```

This will convert all existing tabs in files to spaces.

If you don't want to use `retab`, you can use `perl` to replace each tab by 4 spaces:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\t/    /g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific file you can run the following while being in `vim`

You will need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to create `^I`.

```
:%s /^I/^I^I^I^I/g
```

Comment: it did not work me.

Comment: That is quite strange. I'm not sure if you used literal `^I` or the one I explained in the answer

Comment: I guess command could be :%s /^I/[4spaces]/g

Comment: Well, yes if you want to replace the tab `^I` with spaces then you indeed put spaces there as `:%s /^I/    /g` In your example(question)  You've 4 `^I^I^I^I` which indicate tabs.